# "Please sign in using one of the owner's previous accounts for this device."

Tags: factory-reset, huawei, frp

After resetting my Huawei Honor 8 I'm asked to log into a previously added google account.

I clicked on "I forgot my email" and added my phone number. After this google showed me all the email accounts attached to this phone.

I then tried to log into the account with all of those accounts but I always get the same message: "Please sign in using one of the owner's previous accounts for this device."

This phone has always been mine so the account can't be someone elses.

Comment: I am still unable to  log into my phone. I have tried every single account I own to log in. At this point it seems more that the problem is on googles side. The answer below also didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If for sure you have forgotten your primary mail, for as far as I know, there's no guaranteed way of knowing the mail, you should rather prefer bypassing the lock instead of trying to get to remember the mail, here:

At the very beginning from the Welcome panel choose appropriate language.

Afterwards connect your device to one of the available wifi networks.From the Verifying your account panel active the keyboard to input the email.

In the next step press and hold the icon from the left-down corner of keyboard.

As soon as Huawei Swype menu appears on the screen choose the Help.

After that tap Version and the select Swype.

From the text in front of you click the first link and choose Browser.

You can now use the Internet browser. Type in the following phrase in the searcher: download.hardreset.info

Next choose Huawei folder and download Huawei Bypass Google file.

Open the menu of the browser by tapping the Middle key.

Then select Download options.

In the next step open the Bypass application.

When the Install blocked screen appears on the screen choose Unblock.

Afterwards tap Install and accept necessary conditions.

Tap Open icon and Cancel for the Delete installation package.

Excellent! You are right now in the Main screen of your phone.From the main menu choose Settings .

In the next step tap Backup & Reset and select Factory data reset.

Then choose Reset phone, and confirm the whole operation tapping Reset phone again.

Good job! Wait to accomplish the process! This operation removes your Factory Restet Protection.

If incase you switched to another input method. Hard reset the phone again as below:

First of all, hold down the Power key in order to turn off the device.

Next, press and hold the Volume Up + Power button at the same time for a few seconds.

Let go of held keys as soon as the Huawei logo appears on the screen.Then select by using Volume buttons option "wipe data/factory reset", and confirm that with Power button.

Once more choose "wipe data/factory reset"  from the menu, and accept it with Power key.

When the Recovery Menu pops up accept option "reboot system now" by using Power button.

Congratulations! You have just performed the hard reset operation

Boot it up and try again the previous procedure to bypass the verification

Comment: Do you know if there's any way to find that mail?

Comment: Finding the mail is not the only way to bypass that verification since your primary concern is getting the phone to a useable state. You can do this to get it working again since there's no way of knowing that mail that may be straight forward. Check the edited answer

Comment: What way would you recommend to bypass it?

Comment: I have just updated the answer

Comment: Hard Reset it again

Comment: Yeah I just did that but now when I hold the icon the keyboard just disappears. It doesn't open huawei swype.